# DefaultThreadCurrentCulture in ASP.NET MVC 5 Full Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, cultureinfo

In our ASP.NET MVC 5 project we set the **Culture of the main thread based** on the value of a cookie so that the full Request is run under the same culture.

We'd like to start using the **Async** support. If we set the **DefaultThreadCurrentCulture** when the *Request* starts, will this cause all threads on this, and only this, *Request* to run as the defined culture?

The site gets a lot of traffic so I am worried that if I use **DefaultThreadCurrentCulture** that it will affect other user's as their Requests come in at the same instant.

```
 My BaseController
   {
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string defaultCulture = "fr-CA"; //From Cookie in reality

        // Modify current thread's cultures            
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture= Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture= Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601578/async-webapi-thread-currentculture

Answer (score 2):

I have bad news, good news, and bad news.

#### Bad News

First, the new 4.5 properties `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` apparently are global settings rather than per-request settings.  Notice the reflected code shows no signs of `ExecutionContext` or `CallContext`:

```
    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static CultureInfo DefaultThreadCurrentCulture
    {
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        get
        {
            return CultureInfo.s_DefaultThreadCurrentCulture;
        }
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread=true)]
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        set
        {
            CultureInfo.s_DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = value;
        }
    }

    [__DynamicallyInvokable]
    public static CultureInfo DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture
    {
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        get
        {
            return CultureInfo.s_DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture;
        }
        [__DynamicallyInvokable]
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread=true)]
        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                CultureInfo.VerifyCultureName(value, true);
            }
            CultureInfo.s_DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = value;
        }
    }
```

#### Good News

Fortunately, the custom ASP.NET [AspNetSynchronizationContext apparently handles CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067053/async-call-to-the-wcf-service-doesnt-preserve-currentculture/20087132#20087132) so that it *does* flow between threads as you would hope.

However...

#### Bad News

There was a [bug identified with AspNetSynchronizationContext](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809096) which, if it is still unfixed, suggests the mechanism to "flow" CultureInfo might be unstable.